# Mini edit in Mininet

Tags: python, networking, wireshark, mininet

Good day all,

Guys I am kind of new to Mininet and I’ve installed the SW successfully but not sure how to add mini edit to start creating topology?

And how to add in Mininet the Wireshark ?

Appreciate your help

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark is a separate software used for capturing the packets.
If you are using ubuntu you can just do:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wireshark
```

to see all the traffic generated by mininet, you can capture any interface or the single virtual interfaces.

For miniedit, there is the example file in the github repository, you have to clone the repository and run it.

For example:

```
git clone https://github.com/mininet/mininet.git
cd mininet
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:mininet:
python examples/miniedit.py
```